# How do I put buttons next to each other in linear layout in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-linearlayout

Hello I am trying to put two buttons next to eachother in android studio with linearlayout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="222dp"
    android:layout_height="237dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="246dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="322dp" />

<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/cameraBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/camera"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:strokeColor="@color/teal_700"
    app:cornerRadius="100dp"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"/>

<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/galleryBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Gallery"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:cornerRadius="100dp"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
    />
```

the output currently is:

[image]

I have tried with relativelayout - didn't work and also using horizontal in linearlayout.

I have tried putting also the android:layout_weight as 1 and the buttons disappeared.

I want to have the imageview in the center and the two buttons below and the two buttons are next to each other.

Comment: hi, perhaps the width of the parent needs adjusting to fit?

Comment: Is it mandatory to use Linear Layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another `Linear Layout` inside the parent layout and set its orientation to horizontal to achieve the desired output.
[image: Output]

### Code For Desired Output:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="222dp"
    android:layout_height="237dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="246dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="322dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/cameraBtn"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/camera"
        app:cornerRadius="100dp"
        app:strokeColor="@color/teal_700" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/galleryBtn"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Gallery"
        app:cornerRadius="100dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Kindly up vote the answer as it can help others in future.

Answer (score 1):

If you are intending to keep this view inside of a LinearLayout this is how you will do it. You will add a new LinearLayout below your ImageView and set its orientation or horizontal. Then add your buttons inside of that LinearLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="222dp"
        android:layout_height="237dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/cameraBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/camera"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:strokeColor="@color/teal_700"
            app:cornerRadius="100dp"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"/>

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/galleryBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Gallery"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:cornerRadius="100dp"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

If you are interested in using ConstraintLayout this is how you would do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="222dp"
        android:layout_height="237dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/cameraBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/camera"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:strokeColor="@color/teal_700"
        app:cornerRadius="100dp"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/galleryBtn"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/galleryBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Gallery"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:cornerRadius="100dp"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cameraBtn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your current layout, all the elements are in one container, that is your LinearLayout.

One idea to achieve what you want with a LinearLayout is to separate the image and buttons in 2 different LinearLayouts.
The orientation of the LinearLayout that will host your buttons should be horizontal.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="222dp"
        android:layout_height="237dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="246dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="322dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/cameraBtn"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/camera"
            app:cornerRadius="100dp"
            app:strokeColor="@color/teal_700" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/galleryBtn"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Gallery"
            app:cornerRadius="100dp" />
    </linearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

If the LinearLayout isn't a hard requirement, I would suggest to use ConstraintLayout. By using that, you can position everything in a much better and easy way.

Comment: ty very much I will try to use ConstraintLayout

Comment: you can use linear as well and it will fit into each device as per the size of the device.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use another linear layout to put two button besides each other,
Here is the code for this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="222dp"
        android:layout_height="237dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="246dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="322dp" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/cameraBtn"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Camera"
            app:cornerRadius="100dp"
            app:strokeColor="@color/teal_700" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/galleryBtn"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Gallery"
            app:cornerRadius="100dp" />
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the screenshot of the desired output.
you can give desired margins to set the buttons in the layout.
[image: Desired output]

Answer (score 0):

The outer (main) layout has a **vertical** orientation, so all the elements inside this layout will be arranged vertically, So in order to have these two buttons next to each other you have to use inner
`linearlayout` (inside the main layout) and set its 'orientation' to **horizontal**.